# Get hash from url and click link with data-attribute on page load

Tags: jquery, hash, attributes

My problem is this. Let's say my page has the url [www.mysite.com/test](http://www.mysite.com/test) . Inside this test page there is a link with data-id="vmax".

```
<a href="some-url-here-doesn't-matter" data-id="vmax">Link</a>
```

So if I visit the url with the hash #vmax, like  [www.mysite.com/test/#vmax](http://www.mysite.com/test/#vmax), I need to get the #vmax part, remove the # and click the link with data-id="vmax"

What I tried till now is this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
var targetHash=jQuery(window.location.hash.slice(1));
    console.log(targetHash);
    jQuery('a[data-slug="'+targetHash+'"]').click();})
```

The console log tells me that the # from the hash has been removed succesfully but the click event never happens. Actually the console.log gives this line in the debugger: **n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "vmax"]**

If I change the code to

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
var targetHash=jQuery(window.location.hash.slice(1));
    console.log(targetHash);
    jQuery('a[data-slug="vmax"]').click();})
```

the click event happens succesfully.
As, a probably silly idea, I tried to convert the variable targetHash to a string with the String() function but console.log lost the vmax part completely... so the string was useless...

How can I solve this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...
instead of `var targetHash=jQuery(window.location.hash.slice(1));` I changed the variable to `var targetHash=window.location.hash.slice(1);`
Shouldn't have wrapped it in jquery... :/.